# Linking Phone Call to Account

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Making a workflow in CRM 2013 but can't seem to get access to the field I want. I want the Account Name field on a Phone Call to be populated from the Account Field of the Contact that is on the Call To field.

[image]

I can create the update process (triggered when the Phone Call is created or when the Call To is updated), but I'm unsure of how to access the fields within the Call To entity.

[image]

The form assistant doesn't seem to give me much access to the fields under the entity selected in the Call To field. You can see what I've tried to do in yellow but this doesn't appear to do anything. I've tested it and I know the process is definitely triggered. So when triggered it should get the Account Name field from the Contact in the Call To field and insert it into the Account Name field on the Phone Call.

I'm assuming that there's something on the field level of either the Call To or Account Name fields that are not allowing me to get/insert from another form.

Let me know if this isn't clear and I can explain further.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer that you want but you can only meet this requirement with a custom `CodeActivity`. That class will need to take the Phone Call and if the **Call To** field is a `contact` retrieve the `contact` record, get the account's name (it should be in the `EntityReference.Name` property of the field, and return that as a string value.

The problem is that **Call To** is not guaranteed to be a `Contact` so the CRM Workflow designer doesn't allow you access to the fields. Personally, I wish it worked differently and treated that field as the same as the **Regarding** field but that is not how it was implemented.